# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Подскажите плиз, выдает вот такую ошибку:
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function CartController::actionDelete(), 0 passed in F:\xampp\htdocs\components\Router.php on line 61 and exactly 1 expected in F:\xampp\htdocs\controllers\CartController.php:20 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\components\Router.php(61): CartController->actionDelete() #1 F:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(20): Router->run() #2 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\controllers\CartController.php on line 20

код: cartController:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        // Удаляем заданный товар из корзины
        Cart::deleteProduct($id);
        // Возвращаем пользователя в корзину
        header("Location: /cart");
    }
```

код метода deleteProduct класса Cart:

```
public static function deleteProduct($id)
    {
        // Получаем массив с идентификаторами и количеством товаров в корзине
        $productsInCart = self::getProducts();
        // Удаляем из массива элемент с указанным id
        unset($productsInCart[$id]);
        // Записываем массив товаров с удаленным элементом в сессию
        $_SESSION['products'] = $productsInCart;
    }
```

Comment: Что за фреймворк?

Comment: Ну вы не передаете $id в экшен. Смотрите роутинг

Answer (score 1):

ответ найден.в маршрутах забыл прописать $1

```
('cart/delete/([0-9]+)' => 'cart/delete/$1',)
```